# Not specifying all possible respond_to formats in a Rails session controller before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have an app that will receive both HTML & JSON requests. I have a number of :before_filters in the sessions_controller to detect for various conditions and apply redirects or errors based on these. Most of these explicitly respond_to both html & json.

I have one before_filter that I only want to run if it the request is for HTML. If the request is JSON, I want it to silently return control to the sessions_controller.

I have written it like this:

```
before_filter :check_condition, :only => :create

def check_condition
   respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
       if current_user.meets_condition?
         current_user.do_some_things!
         redirect_to home_path and return
       end
    end
   end
end
```

Does it make any sense to use the respond_to do loop here if I am only responding to HTML requests? And, will this silently pass control back to the sessions_controller if the request is JSON?

Comment: have you tried to add format.json block ?

Comment: Is it necessary to add format.json here, if I do not want to give format.json any particular instructions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the shortest way would be to put `return unless request.format == 'html'` at the beginning of the method. This would do nothing unless the request format is html. In the rest of the method you can just assume an html format.